# How to ignore the Default Style for a particular control?

Tags: wpf

I am using a custom style that is applied to all expanders in my app.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Expander}" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
</Style>
```

In one particular view, I would like to use the standard expander. How can I say it should ignore the custom style and use the built in one?

Unless there is no way and I have to mark the custom style with a key and apply it to all the other expanders with that key. (Therefore the inverse of what I trying to achieve)

I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You *have* specified a key in your example style.  I guess that's not what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<Expander ... Style="{x:Null}" ... />`
in order to ignore the default style.